# Load .tdms file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, labview

Helo,

I have ***.tdms** file exported from LabView.
How can it be loaded in Matlab 2015 or v 2016 64 bit for better data processing?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to grab a reader from the Matlab File Exchange, I use the following one in my work:  https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30023-tdms-reader

You can use it by running something like:

```
MyData = TDMS_readTDMSFile('MyGenericFileName.tdms');
```